# Optional file dependencies in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to specify optional dependencies in Bazel?

I'd like to make a rule to somewhat mirror Kitware's [ExternalData](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalData.html), but I would like to see if I can enable workflows where the developer edits the file in-tree, ideally without needing to modify the `BUILD` file.

### Ideal Workflow

- Define a rule, `external_data`, which can fetch a file from a given server given its SHA-512.
- If the file already exists, check it's SHA-512.

  - If that is what is requested, symlink / copy this file (ensuring that no tests can modify the original file).
  - If it is different, print a *warning*, but proceed as normal, to allow for developers to quickly modify the large files as they need.

I would like to do this such that Bazel can switch between the file being present and not, and be robust to false-positives on caching. An example scenario that I would like to avoid, if I were to not include it as an optional dependency:

1. In a prior run, the file was in the workspace, Bazel built the target, everything's fine and dandy.
2. Developer removes the file from the workspace after uploading, satisfied with their changes and wanting to test the download process.
3. When running the downstream target, Bazel doesn't care about the change in the workspace since it's not an explicit dependency, and the symlink is invalidated, and the test crashes and burns.

To me, it seems like I'd run into this if I tried to implement a <s>`repository_rule`</s> `rule` which manually checks for the file existence, and conditionally executes (I'm not sure if analysis would retrigger this rule being "evaluated" if Step 2 happens.).

### Workaround

My current thought for an alternative workflow is to have an explicit option for `external_data`, `use_workspace`: if `False`, it will download the file; if `True`, it will just mirror `exports_files([])`. The developer can then set this when modifying files.

(Ideally, I'd like to *optionally* include a file which indicates the SHA (`${file}.sha512`), but this seems to go back to the original ask.)

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly that you want a repository_rule that can first check in a local_repository() for some target, and if it's not there, fetch the repository/file from an URL? A combination of local_repository() and http_archive()?

Comment: I apologize, I had meant just a `rule`. And this would be just for an in-repository file, not necessarily a separate workspace / repository. Thank you for asking! Also, I may have a workaround for this; I will post the potential solution, but leave this question open for a while longer.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use Bazel's `glob(...)` method to effectively check for file existence.

If you have a file, say `basic.bin.sha512`, and you want a rule to switch modes based on that file's existence, you can use `glob(["basic.bin.sha512"])`, which will either match the package file exactly or return an empty list.

I had tinkered around with using this on larger sets of files, and it appears to work. However, for the time being, I've erred to having a sort-of explicit "development" mode for the target definition to keep the Bazel build relatively consistent, regardless of what files may be checked out.

Here's an example usage:

https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/external_data_bazel/blob/4bf1dff/WORKFLOWS.md#edit-files-in-a-sha512-group